# RcppArmadillo: vector of arma::cube's

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm developing an application in R / Rcpp using RcppArmadillo, and I need to work with a vector of arma::cube objects. The following example works fine.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool posterior(int n, int L, NumericVector N, int TIME) {
    vector<cube> A(TIME);
    for (int t = 0; t < TIME; t++) A[t] = cube(n, L, max(N), fill::zeros);

    Rprintf("*** %.2f ***\n", A[3].at(5, 1, 2));

    return true;
}
```

Here is some R code to test it.

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("VectorOfCubes.cpp")

posterior(200, 3, c(10, 5, 2), 10^4)
```

My question is: Can I eliminate the `for` in the C++ function above and initialize the vector A directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the default [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) constructor?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool posterior_default(int n, int L, Rcpp::NumericVector N, int TIME) {
  std::vector<arma::cube> A(TIME, arma::cube(n, L, max(N), arma::fill::zeros));

  return true;
}
```

You can use the [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) algorithm, c.f.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool posterior(int n, int L, Rcpp::NumericVector N, int TIME) {
  std::vector<arma::cube> A(TIME);

  std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), arma::cube(n, L, max(N), arma::fill::zeros));

  return true;
}
```

Though, a simpler variant would be to use the [`arma::field`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) to store the values instead of `std::vector` and then use the [`.fill()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fill) member function.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::field<arma::cube> posterior_field(int n, int L, Rcpp::NumericVector N, int TIME) {
  arma::field<arma::cube> A(TIME);

  A.fill(arma::cube(n, L, max(N), arma::fill::zeros));

  return A;
}
```

Output:

```
posterior_field(3, 4, c(1,2,3), 10)
#      [,1]      
# [1,] Numeric,36
# [2,] Numeric,36
# [3,] Numeric,36
# [4,] Numeric,36
# [5,] Numeric,36
# [6,] Numeric,36
# [7,] Numeric,36
# [8,] Numeric,36
# [9,] Numeric,36
# [10,] Numeric,36
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you a lot!

Comment: One more thing. Using your second suggestion `arma::field<arma::cube> A(TIME); A.fill(arma::cube(n, L, max(N), arma::fill::zeros));`, I access the elements as `A[1].at(5, 1, 2)`. But `at()` doesn't check the bounds, right? I there a way to access the elements checking the bounds?

Comment: Correct [`.at()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) does not do bounds checks. To work with 2D or 3D subsets _with_ bounds checks, you will need to use [`(x,y)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) or [`(x,y,z)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access). e.g. `double b =  A[1](5, 1, 2);`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you again.